# Unable to stop com.docker.service

Tags: vb.net, docker, service

Very strange and I really hate to ask because there is lot of topics on this issue but I could not solve it with any help.

I want to stop `docker` completely so Im able to stop `Docker Desktop.exe` but I'm not able to stop the service called: `com.docker.service` it says:

> ERROR: The process "com.docker.service" with PID 10584 could not be terminated.
> Reason: Access is denied..

But I see in my task manager that service. I tried also shell: `Shell("taskkill /F /IM com.docker.service /T", 0)` but not works.

This `Sub` can stop `Docker Desktop.exe` but if I add `com.docker.service` it will not kill it so I can not check wether Docker is started or not because it opens more files in task manager.

```
Public Sub stopDocker()
    Try
        cmd.Kill()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    psi = New ProcessStartInfo("cmd", String.Format("taskkill /F /IM Docker Desktop.exe /T", 0))

    Dim systemencoding As System.Text.Encoding
    System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage)
    With psi
        .UseShellExecute = False
        .RedirectStandardError = True
        .RedirectStandardOutput = True
        .RedirectStandardInput = True
        .CreateNoWindow = True
        .StandardOutputEncoding = systemencoding
        .StandardErrorEncoding = systemencoding
    End With
    cmd = New Process With {.StartInfo = psi, .EnableRaisingEvents = True}
    AddHandler cmd.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf Async_Data_Received
    AddHandler cmd.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf Async_Data_Received
    cmd.Start()
    cmd.BeginOutputReadLine()
    cmd.BeginErrorReadLine()

End Sub
```

**AND FINALLY** I can check if the `com.docker.service` is running with this:

```
If Process.GetProcessesByName("com.docker.service").Length <> 0 Then
   MessageBox.Show("docker running")
End if
```

BUT I am unable to check if `Docker Desktop.exe` is running, I think because there is space I'm not sure.

```
If Process.GetProcessesByName("Docker Desktop.exe").Length <> 0 Then
  MessageBox.Show("docker running")
End if
```

Comment: Have you tried ending the service with elevated privileges?

Comment: @Hursey how do I do that?

Comment: Right click your exe and select "Run as Administrator"

Comment: lol you funny ! I run the command FROM my VB.NET code lol

Comment: Does your program not get compiled to a exe?